# How to align instances with the direction of the armature bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, geometry-nodes

I use the following setup to create a kind of "scale effect" with *Geometry Nodes*:

[image: Setup for "scales"]

However, the tips of the triangular "scales" should not only correspond with their *Z-axis* to the normals of the original geometry, but also point in the direction in which the bones (or at least the nearest bone) point. The rotation of the bones can change, of course, since they are used to deform the entire mesh.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I should proceed?

The blend file can be found here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is currently constructed, it will be difficult or impossible to reliably find the direction and apply it to the objects.

The main problem is that the bones are not geometry that can be used for alignment or that can be used with *Geometry Nodes*.

But you may be able to achieve the desired result by a little restructuring.

Proceed as follows:

1. First create a cylinder that stands upright. Scale the segments as you like and apply your *Vertex Groups* as usual, so that this mesh can follow the *Armature*.

   [image]
2. Then create a *Geometry Nodes* modifier before (!) *Armature*. Omit the *Subdivision* modifier altogether here.

   The *Geometry Nodes* have the following task: Since the bones have no geometry, you simply create them.

   By scaling the geometry towards the center and joining the points, you get a centerline.

   And then You have two meshes stored in your geometry after this action:

   - The original mesh
   - The mesh reduced to a single line in the form of a centerline.

   [image]
3. Then apply the *Armature* modifier, and bend the sausage as you like. The *Armature* is applied to the whole mesh, both parts (the original mesh, and the centerline created from it).

   [image]
4. And now comes the crucial part:

   I start by separating the existing geometry using the *Island Index*. Since two meshes with *Geometry Nodes* were created before, they also have a different numbering.

   I convert the mesh of the centerline into a curve with `Mesh to Curve`, and thus get the tangents of the curve. These tangents always point in the direction in which the mesh runs.

   Additionally I use the node `Subdivision Surface` on the original mesh. This replaces the previously removed modifier *Subdivision*.

   And now the tangents of the centerline as well as the normals of the edges can be used to create a suitable rotation for the points, at which you then only need to instantiate your shapes.

   [image]

[image]